# Alternative to Scriptographer

Tags: adobe-illustrator, plugin

I used Scriptographer a good while back (http://scriptographer.org/)

I wanted to use it again but they no longer work on the latest version of Illustrator - does anyone know an alternative version?

They know use paper.js  But I haven't a clue how it works.  Someone also said Process but does that invovle JavaScript?

Hope you can help.

Steve

Comment: Why not install an older version of Illustrator for this?

Comment: I am unable to get a licences for an older version and it interferes with my current CC :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mr Doob has made a really nice browser based tool, very similar to Scriptographer http://mrdoob.com/#/120/harmony

I would also like a return of Scriptographer. I would like to see Adobe step up and develop this functionality.